# Displaying data from node.js server to html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to show my form data to another html page. This is my server.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app     = express();
var path=require('path');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
app.post('/myaction.html', function(req, res) {
  res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.name + '".');
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
});
```

And this is my 'index.html'

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Demo Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contact">
    <h1>Enter the values</h1>
    <form action="/myaction.html" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" />

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" />

            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea id="message" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
            
            <input type="submit" value="Send message" />

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, it is working properly and the name is reflecting in the myaction.html page. But I want to stylize the 'myaction.html' page a bit and make it look more presentable. Is there any way to add more html tags and text to the page or to display the form data in an already existing page?

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a template engine. A good one is EJS. First you have to use `npm install ejs` and then `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` inside your server.js . After that you will be able to create a new folder in your project named `views` and inside you can create index.ejs and other views files. Inside your server.js you can use `res.render('index.ejs', {data: aJavascriptVariable, data1: moreVars});` . Finally to use this variables inside the .ejs files you can use <%= data %> or <%= data1 %>. Of course html can be written inside a .ejs file.